# Keycloak-js session not terminated when calling .logout()

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have an issue where the keycloak session is still active after calling .logout() from my angular application keycloak-js.

Is there a way to end the session when calling logout?

Keycloak-js v 7.0.1
Keycloak server: 7.4.4

Initializing Keycloak as below

```
this.keycloak.init({
   onLoad: 'check-sso',
   checkLoginIframe: false
}
```

Then logout

```
this.keycloak.logout({redirectUri: redirectUri});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to invoke the logout endpoint with id_token to end the session in case you are using OpenID Connect client login:

> For other browser applications, you can redirect the browser to http://auth-server/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout, which logs the user out if that user has an SSO session with his browser.

[More Info Here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout)